Is the any way to push Windows Event Forwarder logs to my java application irrespective of the platform(linux,mac,windows)
I have a java project
I am trying to get events from WEF without using any agent.
But this should be platform independent, I want to run my project in any OS.
Please let me know if this is possible!
There are some JNA libraries to pull the logs.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jline/jline-terminal-jna
but I want the WEF to push the events to my listening server.

"Windows Event Forwarder" is for windows so I doubt it will work in other platform.

If I understand the documentation correctly WEF runs on a Windows machine and would forward the events to a Windows Event Collector server - which you'd want to be a Java application, is that correct? If so, as long as you can implement the protocol WEF is using it should be independent of OS. However, the protocol might be tied to Windows in which case replicating it on another OS might be very hard.

Is it possible to implement the WEF protocol in my project
